# C# -Asp.net MVC Home/Index page redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been develop a site for sometime but recently had this problem ,home/index page always redirect to login page ,and you can't see it unless you're logged in,Home Controller is surrounded with [AllowAnonymous] 
my defulat route is still the same .

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I don't what can cause this problem ,I've never had this before, I've tried adding and removing [AllowAnonymous] ,still the same problem ,but the weird thing is Index is the only action in home controller require login,else work fine

```
[AllowAnonymous]
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {

                    var types = (from r in db.FeedBack
                                 select new FeedBackView { ID = r.ID, Name = r.Name, Jop = r.Jop, Body = r.Body }).Take(7).ToList();
                    var SlidersList = (from r in db.Sliders
                                       select new SliderView { Description = r.Description, Title = r.Title, ImageURL = r.ImageURL }).ToList();
                    var FeaturesList = (from r in db.Features
                                        select new FeatureView { Description = r.Description, Title = r.Title, ImageURL = r.ImageURL }).ToList();
                    var AccordionList = (from r in db.Accordion
                                         select new AccordionView { Description = r.Description, Title = r.Title, ImageURL = r.ImageURL }).ToList();
                    var ServicesList = (from r in db.Services
                                        select new ServiceView { Body = r.Body, Name = r.Name, ImageURL = r.ImageURL, Glaphicon = r.Glaphicon, ID = r.ID }).Take(6).ToList();

                    var portfolioTypesList = (from r in db.PortfolioTypes
                                              select new PortfolioTypeView { Name = r.Name, ID = r.ID, filter = r.filter }).Take(5).ToList();
                    List<PortfolioView> Portfolios = new List<PortfolioView>();
                    List<PortfolioView> toadd = new List<PortfolioView>();
                    portfolioTypesList.ForEach(r =>
                    {
                        //Portfolios.AddRange((from s in db.Portfolios
                        //                     where s.PortfolioTypeID == r.ID
                        //                     select new PortfolioView { TypeName = r.Name, ID = s.ID, filter = r.filter, ProjectName = s.ProjectName }
                        //                         ).Take(6).ToList());

                        toadd = (from s in db.Portfolios
                                 where s.PortfolioTypeID == r.ID
                                 select new PortfolioView { TypeName = r.Name, ID = s.ID, filter = r.filter, ProjectName = s.ProjectName }).Take(6).ToList();
                        Portfolios.AddRange(toadd);
                    });

                    var x = new List<PortfolioView>();
                    PortfolioImage im = new PortfolioImage();
                    Portfolios.ForEach(r =>
                    {
                        im = db.PortfolioImages.Where(s => s.PortfolioID == r.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (im != null)
                        {
                            x.Add(new PortfolioView()
                            {
                                ID = r.ID,
                                TypeName = r.TypeName,
                                ProjectName = r.ProjectName,
                                URL = im.ImageURL,
                                filter = r.filter
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            x.Add(new PortfolioView()
                            {
                                ID = r.ID,
                                TypeName = r.TypeName,
                                ProjectName = r.ProjectName,
                                URL = "",
                                filter = r.filter
                            });
                        }
                    }
                           );

                    var Articels = (from e in db.Articles
                                    select new ArticleViewModel
                                    {
                                        Body = e.Body,
                                        Title = e.Title,
                                        ImageURL = e.ImageURL,
                                        ID = e.ID
                                    }).Take(3).ToList();

                    //var Social = db.Others.FirstOrDefault();
                    //ViewBag.Social = SocialMedia.convert(Social);                
                    ViewBag.Articels = Articels;
                    ViewBag.portfolioTypesList = portfolioTypesList;
                    ViewBag.Portfolios = x;
                    ViewBag.ServicesList = ServicesList;
                    ViewBag.AccordionList = AccordionList;
                    ViewBag.SliderList = SlidersList;
                    ViewBag.FeaturesList = FeaturesList;
                    ViewBag.FeedBackGo = types;
                    return View();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error");
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: the controller has the [Authorize] attribute? elaborate your question...

Comment: no ,the controller has no [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: I think that showing us the controller code (or at least the Index action) would be helpful

Comment: have you tried remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute? What the asp mvc version?

Comment: yes I tried ,still the same problem.

Comment: do you have a `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` registered on `RegisterGlobalFilters`?

Comment: no .should i add this filter,there is this filter                                      filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

Comment: no, when started happen this? have you tried clean the solution? take a look at this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: I took a look, it didn't help

Comment: is there is any thing that i can look at in the webconfig,that maybe causing this problem

Comment: can you post the `<authentication />` part of your web.config?

Comment: <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

Comment: @PauloDiogo <authentication mode="None" />

Comment: @theprogrammer_man are you using owin?

Comment: @PauloDiogo No I'm not using owin

Comment: @theprogrammer_man how do you redirecst to login page? what the mvc version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVC 5 , redirecting to login page come from the authorize attribute @PauloDiogo

Comment: @theprogrammer_man there is no a Startup.cs file in your project?

Comment: @PauloDiogo there is Startup.cs file in my project

Comment: @PauloDiogo I don't know if owin come by default in asp.net mvc 5 ,so let me after we discovered there is owin ,how solve this?

Comment: try put `[Authorize]` in controller and `[AllowAnonymous]` on action that you want public access. After this look at `Startup.Auth.cs` and verify if it is  equals this https://gist.github.com/paulodiogo/579dc2351ce66c1814b6

Comment: @PauloDiogo there is an additional line in Startup.Auth.cs         app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie); ,with it or with out it ,still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried custom attributes?

For instance let's create an attribute called `CustomAuthorize`

```
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute    
 {

     protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext    
     filterContext)    
     {     
           if (IsUserAuthenticated(filterContext.HttpContext))    
           {    
            filterContext.Result = new   RedirectResult("/Account/InvalidRole");    
           }    
           else    
           {    
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);    
           }    
     }

     private bool IsUserAuthenticated(HttpContextBase context)    
     {    
            return context.User != null && context.User.Identity != null &&     
            context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;    
     }

 }
```

By default the Authorize attribute lead to the login page if the user is not in the right role to access some part of your application.

Now to implement this you should do the following.

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admin,Manager")]
public class MyController
{

      // Everyone has access
      [AllowAnonymous]
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
      return View();
      }

      // Only Admin and Manager roles have access, everyone else is denied
      public ActionResult About()
      {
      return View();
      } 

}
```

Remember to put the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` in cases where everyone can access the Action method. Inside the 'public' method you can include the following to allow role-specific implementations:

```
if(this.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{

}
```

With that you will be redirected to `/Account/InvalidRole` if you don't have the required role. And if you are good to go the page should render normally.

Comment: Thanks,but it did not help

Comment: Please add a breakpoint both in the class and in the action method. Does it even run the class? Is it just with the method?

Comment: I added a breakpoint in the action ,the action did run ,I followed the execution step by step nad when it reach @renderBody in the layout it redirected to login